# ActiveRecord - Search Postgres array with multiple values?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, sinatra

From [this tip](https://coderwall.com/p/sud9ja), i see I can search a Postgres array with a singular value so:

`User.where("'foo@bar.com' = ANY (emails)")`

I was wondering, however, how I could search for multiple values, for example:

`User.where("['foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com'] = ANY (emails)")`

which results in a `PG::SyntaxError`

I am using Activerecord 4.1.1

Comment: have you tried `('foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com')` ?

Comment: Yes, I get `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type record`

Comment: Try then `where("ANY (emails) IN ('foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com'))"` or then `where("IN ('foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com') ANY (emails))"`

Comment: :( The first one seems to run forever until interrupted, producing no results, while the second produced `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IN"`

Answer (score 1):

You want the PostgreSQL array-overlaps or array-contained-by operators, depending on whether you want AND or OR-like behaviour.

```
SELECT ARRAY['foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com'] @@ emails FROM ...
```

or

```
SELECT ARRAY['foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com'] <@ emails FROM ...
```

Making Rails emit PostgreSQL array literals is hopefully fairly easy, but beyond my Rails-fu of nearly nil.

If `emails` is of type `varchar[]` instead of `text[]` then you need to cast the array literal to `varchar` too, e.g.

```
SELECT ARRAY['foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com']::varchar[] <@ emails FROM ...
```

To test out the functionality stand-alone, you can just evaluate standalone expressions, e.g.

```
regress=> SELECT ARRAY['foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com'] <@ ARRAY['foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com', 'fred'];
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi Craig, a call to `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)` would return an array, but I'm confused about how to even get this raw sql statement to work. Generally speaking, I'm getting `HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.` when trying to execute something along the lines of `SELECT ARRAY['foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com'] <@ emails FROM users;`

Comment: @waffl works for me - `SELECT ARRAY['foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com'] <@ ARRAY['foo@bar.com', 'bar@foo.com', 'fred'];`. What data type is `emails`? (The first half of the message, which you left out, usually tells you this). Maybe you need a cast; Pg doesn't implicitly cast array types. Or maybe you're on an old version?

Comment: When I try to run the statement without `FROM`, I get `missing FROM-clause entry for table...` The field is `character varying(255)[]`

Comment: @waffl OK, so you have to cast the input array to `varchar[]`, e.g. `ARRAY['a', 'b']::varchar[]`.